# Can core.autocrlf be pushed to remote repository?

Tags: git, line-endings, core.autocrlf

We have a centralized git repository that has a project only for Windows. So we expect autocrlf be false.

However, somebody also works on cross platform project and set

> git config --global core.autocrlf true

If they forget to change the setting for this windows git repository, then they will commit unix ending file to it which is not expected by us.

So what i want is that:
Regardless of how to set "git config --global core.autocrlf", autocrlf are always false when clone that repo and no need additional step to set it.

I know we can set core.autocrlf for local repo, but how it can be done for the remote repository?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add *and commit* a [`.gitattributes` file](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitattributes.html) which sets `eol=crlf` for the files of types your require to have Windows EOLs (like `*.cs`, `*.*proj` etc).

Or may be just set

```
*       text=auto
```

in that file to have LFs in the repository and whatever your users wish in their work trees.

The exact approach depends on what is already in your repository.

By the way, the comments block in the [`.gitattributes` file from the Mono project](https://github.com/mono/mono/blob/master/.gitattributes) is particularly insightful about the EOL-normalization issues across different platforms.

Answer (score 0):

You can make sure that your user have a `GIT_TEMPLATE_DIR` environment variable set to a "**[template directory](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-init#_template_directory)**" where you have a template git repo.

That template will be use when cloning or initializing a new repo, and can contain a custom template config file.

The question "[Global git hook](https://superuser.com/a/164269/141)" illustrates how that template mechanisms can be use to pre-configure other aspects of a repo as well.

Answer (score 0):

you could install a server-side hook that checks whether the line-endings are correct and refuses/fixes the problem centrally.

see this [GIT CRLF hook](http://gergap.wordpress.com/2010/05/12/git-crlf-hook/) for an example solution (though the other way round)